# SELECT Latest records for each device

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a sensortable which has three fields.

DeviceID, timestamp, Temperature.

I have records being inserted from sensor devices constantly. Hence, there is a chance to have multiple temperature readings for the same deviceID with the same timestamp.

The requirement I have is to write a SELECT statement which will retrieve me one record for each of the device which is the most recent. For example, if there are temperature readings recorded from 5 devices, I just want 5 records to be in the output and each record need to the latest temperature reading for that particular device.

I did bit of research and used the below query.

```
 select 
     s1.g_device as DEVICE, 
     s1.c_temperature as TEMP,
 from sensortable s1
 inner join (
       SELECT  g_device, 
             max(g_created) as mts
       FROM sensortable
       GROUP BY g_device ) s2 
       on s2.g_device = s1.g_device and 
          s1.g_created = s2.mts;
```

However, this query does not work if a Device has different temperature reading on the same timestamp.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeviceID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS N
    FROM sensortable 
)
SELECT *
FROM TT
WHERE N = 1;
```

Comment: How will the query assign row_number when you have the same timestamp for a device?

Comment: If it is the same Timestamp it doesnt matter as even you could not decide which one to use. If a timestamp is not accurate enough for your data, you should use another way to guarantee that you are getting the latest one. So in SQL Server I think it will just take any row if they have the same timestamp

Comment: Hi, I am not using SQL Server. It a SAP HANA Database.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the SQL as below and now it works. SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT deviceID, temperature, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DeviceID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS N
    FROM sensortable 
) AS TT
WHERE N = 1;